# How to resolve "-bash: kubeless: command not found" issue in Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, serverless, kubeless

I have followed all the steps from the Bitnami website. I have installed Helm and Tiller. But when I give the command - `kubeless function ls`, it shows the error:

`-bash: kubeless: command not found`.

Also I have downloaded the `kubeless.zip` file but whenever I proceed to unzip it using: `unzip kubeless.zip`, it says :

```
cannot find zipfile directory in one of kubeless.zip or
kubeless.zip.zip, and cannot find kubeless.zip.ZIP, period.
```

How do I resolve these issues and what do I need to get started with Kubeless in GKE ? I am using Google Cloud Shell to run the commands.

I am in zone asia-south1-b.

Answer (score 0):

kubeless shouldn't be run from the nodes, following the [install guide](https://kubeless.io/docs/quick-start/#installation), you are deploying k8s resources on the cluster, but the kubeless command line should be done from your computer.

Comment: I am actually running the commands in Google Cloud Shell. Will it work if I run the Kubeless command line in an UBUNTU VM in Google Cloud ?

Comment: as long as you install the package first and already have a connection to the cluster (kubeconfig), I'm pretty sure it should work. I haven't tested this yet but I can say with a good deal of confidence this command should not be run from within the nodes

Comment: I'm trying to install kubeless on a CI/CD agent container, and I face this issue. That is a valid problem, isn't it.

Comment: At the end, I had to manually download the latest release and use it in my docker container: https://github.com/amazinsellers/circleci-digitalocean/commit/7a579c8fbddae2ff7c474753dc3b38ef5faa52d5 . Shame it is, but that works. I'll spend time later to find what is the best that can be done.